# How much should PCs be paid?

Tags: earthdawn-1e

I'm GMing an *Earthdawn* campaign, and I've opted for a sandbox approach instead of generic quests with big loot piles at the ends of dungeons.

The PCs--rather than loot killed creatures, hunt for gems, or invest their meager funds--are trying to make honest livings, and I don't know how much money they should make.

- Some skills can be rented, like forge blades, with the prices listed under talents.
- Sages, scribes, and armorers have prices listed for hiring them.

But there are no guidelines for how much a *normal* bodyguard, caravan guard, city guardsman, package delivery person, or merchant, for example, should make, and whatever those occupations make, an *adept* doing the same job should probably make--or, at least *charge*--more.

Are there guidelines for how much an adept should earn from an occupation that *doesn't* involve monster killing? If there aren't, what are some guidelines?

Comment: That was some crazy editing, i think i have like 15 words left in that. However it has a stylish touch now :P

Comment: Sometimes I get carried away. Feel free to revert if your original better expresses the question you have. (By the way, I really wasn't sure what was meant by skills being *rented* nor if that were a game term--I'm not an *Earthdawn* guy--so if that's a real in-game thing, keep it, but otherwise you could clarify what you mean by *rented* skills.)

Comment: well, i'm not an english guy so maybe it wasnt the right term... you know, when you get paid to do a job. Like, the opposite of hiring. If it doesnt get answers, i suppose i'll revert it back and see if people prefer my gibberish :P

Comment: @Mouhgouda "skills can be rented" would be easily understood by a native speaker. It's not exactly idiomatic, but the meaning is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a long time Earthdawn GM, I've settled on using the Circle Training rules to gauge pay for Adepts. This is found in Earthdawn 1st edition in Building Your Legend, page 222. The chart starts at circle 2, but you can fill in circle 1 at 100 silver. The table represents 40 hours of training (within a 3 week period), so a week of normal 8 hrs a day work. This also lines up with the mentioned Barsaive Campaign Set reference. In the Barsaive Gamemaster's Book, page 10. The Cost of Living table shows:

```
Standard    | Cost
------------+------------------------
Squalid     | 5sp/month
Poor        | 25sp/month
Comfortable | 150sp/Circle per month
Wealthy     | 350sp/Circle per month
```

So a first Circle adept, working 4 weeks @ 100 sp per week, would spend about 3/8 of his income on basic standard of living to be Comfortable.

Answer (score 3):

I'll be writing this from memory, because I don't have the books on me, so take everything here with a grain of salt. (Lucky me you're not asking for RAW.)

So, first of all, Earthdawn depicts a rather balkanized society: there are segregated islands of Name-giver settlements in a pretty hostile sea of monsters and other hazards. Therefore **costs and wages may vary wildly from place to place.** In remote areas, people might not even use money, but rely on barter and trade entirely instead -- and even larger settlements may have very, very differing prices for the same thing. What's easy to get in one city may well be a luxury item in another, and vice versa. (That's what makes trading worth it, even despite the immense risks involved.) So, **services provided by people--normal people, let alone adepts--will have varying prices as well.**

As a rule of thumb, I'd rely on the "cost of living" information in the Barsaive boxed set (which, again, I don't have on me at the moment...) As far as I can remember, it says that **a comfortable lifestyle costs about 150sp per Circle per month, which means about 5sp per day for an adept of the 1st Circle. This, in turn, means that that's the minimum a character should earn a day to maintain a comfortable life.** Less than that, the character is poor. Multiply that by five or ten, and you have someone noticeably wealthy. This should give you an idea about how much your PCs should be offered, and how much they can ask for... *in general*.

Of course, their wage will depend a lot on the factors I've mentioned above. Are they in a region where there are many dangers and few guards? They may earn a lot more than 5sp a day. Are they in a calm city with a strong authority maintaining a strong guard? Good luck trying to find work as standard, unofficial guards for hire.

Regarding the "how much do non-adepts earn" question: I think their income is roughly 50-75%  of what a first circle adept earns -- if they're doing a job for which there's average need. That is to say, a normal city guard in a moderately dangerous city would earn 3-4sp a day. A caravan guard would earn the same on a relatively safe, established route. A merchant of goods that have average availability (not of exquisite items, and neither of snow on the North Pole :)) would earn about 3-5sp a day as well.

Remember, Earthdawn is about heroic adventures (and Lovecraftian horrors, if that's what you like in it), not about reliable and well-developed economy simulation. Don't let your game get bogged down by haggling over an sp or two (especially not out of game): set a wage for a job that feels right for the job and the geographic/social/etc area, and get on with your story. :)

Comment: i don't intend to let them go old being city guards, they just kind of need a hook (and i don't think a hobo could provide a wanabe hero group a suitable adventure), and being without experience and poor, they needed a bit of gold (poor and without equipment, a trek through the wilderness is the best way to starve to death). So i set them a caravan job to launch their career. I'll try finding where it said 125sp per circle per month is confortable for an adept. Any idea in what book that was, per chance?

Comment: As I've mentioned, it's in the [Barsaive Campaign Set](http://index.rpg.net/display-entry.phtml?mainid=6916), which has only two books: the Explorer's Guide and the Gamemaster's Book - the info should be there in one of these. :)